# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowBackground' in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to set image b.jpg as background wallpaper in whole application. I have done as below

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowBackground">@drawable/b</item>
</style>
```

I am getting error as shown below..
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKDWv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/b</item>
```